# Why isn't my Nginx try_files directive working to remove an extension

Tags: nginx-config

My site is a basic PHP site with a Wordpress blog installed in a subdirectory. I need to use pretty URLs, so I need to remove the `.php` extension from the files in root, and then get Wordpress to behave like Wordpress in the `/blog` subdirectory.

I've only been able to get one to work at a time and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This config works for Wordpress, but downloads the .php files in root. :/

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$uri.php /blog/index.php?$query_string;
}
```

#### UPDATE

I've added a separate `location` so now the extension removal is working in root, but the blog links just go back to the site's home page

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php;
}
    
location /blog {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

// also tried this, with the same results
location /blog {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I needed to add `/blog/` as a path inside the `/blog` `/location`

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php;
}
    
location /blog {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php;
}
```